# How to style Google Maps as a two tone coloured map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a two tone map using Google Maps API. I've tried creating custom code using this wizard, but when you zoom into the map you can see certain areas (I'm not sure what they are) in white or green. I was wondering if there was a shortcut for specifying just one colour for land and one for water.

Here is my styling code.

```
var styles = [
            {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#193a70' },
                    { visibility: "on" }
                ]
            },{
                featureType: "landscape",
                 elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { "color": "#2c5ca5" }
                ]


            }
        ];
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrHar/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrHar/2/)

Here is the fix, I was missing 'points of interest' or 'poi' and various other elements.

```
    var styles = [
            {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#193a70' },
                    { visibility: "on" }
                ]
            },
            {
             featureType: "road",
              stylers: [
               { "visibility": "off" }
                  ]
                 },
          {
              featureType: "transit",
   stylers: [
   { "visibility": "off" }
      ]
    },{
       featureType: "administrative",
 stylers: [
   { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
 },  {
    featureType: "landscape",
                 elementType: "all",
                stylers: [
                    { "color": "#2c5ca5" }
                ]
                },{
                featureType: "poi",
                 stylers: [
                 { "color": "#2c5ca5" }

                ]
            },
            {
     elementType: "labels",
stylers: [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
}
        ];
```